# How can I get the value of the mainbooktitle element in a DITA bookmap when the context is a topic or an image?

Tags: dita

When process images in DITA topics, I want to include the book title or the map title. Is that possible? How do I access the book title value in the XSLT context of an image?

Comment: What publishing target ? PDF, HTML or others?

Comment: @tmakita html. Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> How do I access the book title value in the XSLT context of an image?

Provided you are using DITA-OT HTML5 transformation for your HTML publishing, you can access map information from topic template by implementing three extension points described in [Customizing DITA Open Toolkit](https://www.dita-ot.org/dev/topics/customizing.html).

- dita.conductor.html5.param
- dita.conductor.html5.toc.param
- dita.xsl.html5

The sample plug-in structure, named "com.acme.html5.param" and "com.acme.html5":

```
dita-ot-3.3/plugins
   |
   +-- com.acme.html5.param
   |     |
   |     +-- plugin.xml
   |         buildHtml5Param.xml
   |
   +-- com.acme.html5
         |
         +-- plugin.xml
         |
         +--xsl
             |
             +-- dita2html5_acme_custom.xsl
```

[com.acme.html5.param/plugin.xml]

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<plugin id="com.acme.extend.html5.param">
    <feature extension="dita.conductor.html5.param" file="buildHtml5Param.xml"/>
    <feature extension="dita.conductor.html5.toc.param" file="buildHtml5Param.xml"/>
</plugin>
```

[com.acme.html5.param/buildHtml5Param.xml]

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<params xmlns:if="ant:if">
    <param name="input.map.url" expression="${html5.map.url}" if:set="html5.map.url"/>
</params>
```

[com.acme.html5/plugin.xml]

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<plugin id="com.acme.html5">
    <feature extension="dita.xsl.html5" file="xsl/dita2html5_acme_custom.xsl"/>
</plugin>
```

[com.acme.html5/xsl/dita2html5_acme_custom.xsl]

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
    xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
    xmlns:dita-ot="http://dita-ot.sourceforge.net/ns/201007/dita-ot"
    exclude-result-prefixes="xs dita-ot"
    version="2.0">

    <!-- map URL -->
    <xsl:param name="input.map.url" as="xs:anyURI" required="yes"/>

    <!-- map document -->
    <xsl:variable name="mapDoc" as="document-node()" select="doc($input.map.url)"/>

    <!-- map title -->
    <xsl:variable name="title" as="xs:string">
        <xsl:variable name="titleTexts" as="xs:string*">
            <xsl:choose>
                <xsl:when test="$mapDoc/*[contains(@class,' bookmap/bookmap ')]">
                    <xsl:apply-templates select="$mapDoc/*[contains(@class, ' bookmap/bookmap ')]/*[contains(@class, ' bookmap/booktitle ')]/*[contains(@class, ' bookmap/mainbooktitle ')]" mode="dita-ot:text-only"/>
                </xsl:when>
                <xsl:otherwise>
                    <xsl:apply-templates select="$mapDoc/*[contains(@class, ' map/map ')]/*[contains(@class, ' topic/title ')]" mode="dita-ot:text-only"/>
                </xsl:otherwise>
            </xsl:choose>
        </xsl:variable>
        <xsl:sequence select="string-join($titleTexts,'')"/>
    </xsl:variable>

    <!-- override image template -->
    <xsl:template match="*[contains(@class, ' topic/image ')]" name="topic.image">
        <!-- snip! -->
        ...
        <!-- customization here! -->
        <div>Map: <xsl:value-of select="$title"/></div>
    </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

By adding above plug-ins, you can get following sample result when building `dita-ot-3.3/docsrc/samples/sequence.ditamap`.

[dita-ot-3.3/docsrc/samples/sequence.ditamap]

```
<map>
  <title>Working in the garage</title>
  <topicref href="tasks/changingtheoil.xml" type="task"/>
  ...
  <topicref href="tasks/washingthecar.xml" type="task"/>
  ...
</map>
```

[dita-ot-3.3/docsrc/samples/tasks/washingthecar.xml]

[image: washingthecar.html]

Comment: thank you. I am struggling to get the file directory. I want to change the value of href in an xref into just the title of the topic. When I try to use the $Filedir variable, it appends "topics" folder to the current plugin directory, which results in the file not found error. If I append the absolute path to the file name, the entity resolver does not work and it expects the dtd files to be in the topics folder.