# DITA document title and other field value should show in dynamic header or footer

Tags: html, header, customization, dita, dita-ot

We implement dita html5 plugin. We brought custom header and footer as .xml as said in the DITA document. how to populate the DITA document title and other field value should show dynamically in the header or footer

Comment: It would be great if you share any sample or proper document.

Comment: You would need a DITA Open Toolkit plugin which customizes the HTML5 XSLT processing and adds an XSLT stylesheet which loads the main DITA Map using the document() function and extracts its title. Here's a similar question which has an in depth reply: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55514365/how-can-i-get-the-value-of-the-mainbooktitle-element-in-a-dita-bookmap-when-the